# Can I use the webpage functions with selenium? [JAVA]

Tags: javascript, java, function, selenium, methods

I'm using selenium in a page that has javascript in it.

For instance, when clicking on a little x at the left corner of a window, the page calls the function `closeWindow('welcome')`. Can I call this function from selenium without the need of performing a click on the button? It would really speed things up If I could use the page's methods.

I've done my research but I have only seen this related to selenium, javascript and functions:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("yourScript();");
```

I have tried it but it doesn't seem to find the script, in this case `"closeWindow("welcome")"`, even though the button on the page calls it just like that.

I have also found where the page's javascript functions are stored (in a file called game.js) but I don't know if it can be of any use.

Is there any way I can use the page's methods or do I have to stick to clicking buttons?

The html of the button is as follows:

```
<a ng-if="w.params.modalParams.closeable" clickable="closeWindow('welcomeScreen')" class="closeWindow clickable" play-on-click="7">
```

Comment: Two things: the HTML code says "welcomeScreen" but you state that you tried "welcome"  Second, show the exact executeScript line you used - perhaps you missed something that we can spot, like a missing ; or " instead of ', etc.

Comment: About the welcome thing you are right, it should be welcomeScreen but the mistake is just on the question post, in my code I got it correct. And the second thing, i tried both with and without semicolon. it just said function not recognized, I'll try to find the exact exception text

Comment: It actually said "function not defined"